# Is "gate to heaven" "foris paradisi" or "foris paradiso"?

Tags: syntax, morphology

I noticed that the Croatian for "gate to heaven" is "vrata raja", "raja" being the genitive singular (rather than dative) of "raj" (heaven). I was wondering how it is in Latin. Is the Latin for "gate to heaven" a literal translation of "gate to heaven" (so, "foris paradiso") or a literal translation of "vrata raja" (so, "foris paradisi")? Also, is there some linguistic reason Croatian and English differ in this regard? English seems a bit more logical in this regard than Croatian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural way of expressing this would be with the genitive as in the following verse from the *Vulgate*.

> pavensque quam terribilis inquit est locus iste
> non est hic aliud nisi domus Dei et **porta caeli**
> (*Gen. 28:17*)

Here's another use of the genitive:

> Christo apertae sunt **portae caeli** propter carnalem eius
> assumptionem. (*Irenaeus*)

Therefore, given the options you listed, *foris paradisi* would be better than the alternative.

**Is the dative possible?**

A question was raised concerning the possible usage of the dative in this way, based on a proverb cited by @d_e in a comment:

> **porta itineri** longissima

However, such usage has been described as "[remarkable](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/15080/81)" and thus would definitely be considered the exception to the rule.

Generally speaking, the dative is associated with the action of a verb, just as is the case with their corresponding expression in English (i.e. prepositional phrases beginning with *to*). However, in English, the verb is often unexpressed. For example, when we say "the gate to heaven", we understand that to mean "the gate *that leads* to heaven".

Another possibility is the so-called [Dative of Reference](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-reference). However, when such datives are used to express a local point of view, they are usually used with participles. For example:

> oppidum prīmum Thessaliae venientibus ab Ēpīrō
> *the first town of Thessaly as you come from Epirus.*

The Dative of Reference is sometimes also used idiomatically without a verb:

> Quō mihi fortūnam? (*Hor. Ep. 1.5.12*)
> *Of what use to me is fortune?*

In summary, using the dative for *porta caelo* or *foris paradiso* seems very questionable at best.

Comment: With respect to dative, the proverb *porta itineri longissima* comes to mind.  But I'm not sure about the meaning difference with respect to a genitive.

Comment: @d_e Great example! I incorporated it into my answer.

Comment: The dative strikes me as wrong. The construction *porta itineri longissima* seems highly unusual to me. I do not fully understand it (it is probably worth its own question), but I am not convinced *porta itineri* means "the gate to the journey." For one thing, that's not how [Georges](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/porta?hl=longissima) translates it.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. Thanks! I posted a question to address that.

Comment: "Although this expression doesn't appear as such in the Bible" - what about "porta caeli"
(Genesis 28:17)? But the Vulgate and Irenaeus are both translations, so it isn't a great proof for Latin idiom

Comment: @ba You're right! Thanks! I updated my answer.